# python: subclass of subclass of int

Tags: python, inheritance, new-operator

I'm trying to understand how to subclass `int` properly. One goal is to define types used in structures within a certain binary file format. For example, an unsigned, 16-bit integer. I've defined a class as follows, which seems to do what I expect:

```py
class uint16(int):

    def __new__(cls, val):
        if (val < 0 or val > 0xffff):
            raise ValueError("uint16 must be in the range %d to %d" % (0, 0xffff))
        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

Now, I'm not super clear on the use of `super` with no args versus (type, object) versus (type, type). I've used `super(cls, cls)` as I saw that used for a similar scenario.

Now, C makes it easy to create types that are effectively aliases of existing types. For example,

```c
typedef unsigned int        UINT;
```

Aliases might be considered useful to help clarify the intended usage for a type. Whether one agrees or not, a description of a binary format can sometimes do this, and if so, then for clarity it would be helpful to replicate this in Python.

So, I tried the following:

```py
class Offset16(uint16):

    def __new__(cls, val):
        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

I could have made `Offset16` a subclass of `int`, but then I'd want to repeat the validation (more duplicated code). By sub-classing `uint16`, I avoid the duplicate code.

But when I try to construct an Offset16 object, I get a recursion error:

```py
>>> x = Offset16(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __new__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __new__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __new__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __new__
  [Previous line repeated 987 more times]
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __new__
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
>>>
```

Since the call stack just line line 5 repeated (not lines 3/5 in alternation), the line in `uint16.__new__` is getting re-entered.

I then tried revising `Offset16.__new__` in different ways, changing the args to `super`, most of which didn't work. But one last attempt was the following:

```py
class Offset16(uint16):

    def __new__(cls, val):
        return super(uint16, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

This seems to work:

```py
>>> x = Offset16(42)
>>> x
42
>>> type(x)
<class '__main__.Offset16'>
```

Why the difference?

This latter approach seems to defeat part of the purpose of `super`: avoiding reference to the base class to make it easier to maintain. Is there a way to make this work that doesn't require reference to `uint16` within the `__new__` implementation?

And what's the best way to do this?

Comment: No! Do **not** pass `cls` as the first argument to `super()`, instead, pass `super(uint16, cls).__new__(cls)`, if you pass `cls`, you keep sending it back to the same method! If this is python 3, you can simply use `super().__new__(cls, val)` ... Note, `__new__` is a staticmethod basically.

Comment: "This latter approach seems to defeat part of the purpose of super: avoiding reference to the base class to make it easier to maintain." That isn't *really* the purpose of `super`. That is a cherry on top that is really only available possible with Python3.  it is *most* useful in the case of cooperative multiple inheritance, where it gives you the *next* method in the method resolution order. It must know the class that it was called in to determine that. If you dynamically pass it the same class/instance combo, as you are doing, it will keep giving you the same method.

Comment: Note that for a simple alias (same as C `typedef`) you can use simple assignment, like `Offset16 = uint16`. (then `type(x)` will be `<class '__main__.uint16'>`)

Comment: call \_\_new\_\_ of parent class work, like int.\_\_new\_\_(cls, val)  and unit16.\_\_new\_\_(cls, val).

Comment: @Adam.Er8: Of course, hadn't thought of that, but it's probably the closest counterpart to the C `typedef` usage I cited.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: So, to make sure I understand: When `Offset16.__new__` is called, it will call into `uint16` with `__new__(Offset16, val)`. But then within the implementation of that method it will call `super(Offset16, Offset16).__new(Offset16, val)`; and `super(Offset16, Offset16)` will resolve once again to `uint16` and so the same method gets called over recursively. But instead, having `super()` will ensure walking up the inheritance tree. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments have supplied info that has helped answer *Why the difference?* and *What's the best way?*

---

First: *Why the difference?*

In the original definitions of `uint16` and `Offset16`, the `__new__` method uses `super(cls,cls)`. As @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, when `Offset16.__new__` is call it leads to `uint16.__new__` calling itself recursively. By having `Offset16.__new__` use `super(uint16,cls)`, it changes the behaviour inside `uint16.__new__`.

Some additional explanation may help to understand:

The `cls` argument passed into `Offset16.__new__` is the `Offset16` class itself. So, when the implementation of the method refers to `cls`, that is a reference to `Offset16`. So,

```py
    return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

is equivalent in that case to

```py
    return super(Offset16, Offset16).__new__(Offset16, val)
```

Now we might think of `super` as returning the base class, but its semantics when arguments are provided is more subtle: `super` is resolving a reference to a method and the arguments affect how that resolution happens. If no arguments are provided, `super().__new__` is the method in the immediate superclass. When arguments are provided, that affects the search. In particular for `super(type1, type2)`, the MRO (method resolution order) of `type2` will be searched for an occurrence of `type1`, and the *class following type1* in that sequence will be used.

(This is explained in the [documentation of `super`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#super), though the wording could be clearer.)

The MRO for `Offset16` is (Offset16, uint16, int, object). Therefore

```py
    return super(Offset16, Offset16).__new__(Offset16, val)
```

resolves to

```py
    return uint16.__new__(Offset16, val)
```

When `uint16.__new__` is called in this way, the class argument passed to it is `Ofset16`, not `uint16`. As a result, when its implementation has

```py
    return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

that once again will resolve to

```py
    return uint16.__new__(Offset16, val)
```

This is why we end up with an infinite loop.

But in the changed definition of `Offset16`,

```py
class Offset16(uint16):

    def __new__(cls, val):
        return super(uint16, cls).__new__(cls, val)
```

the last line is equivalent to

```py
        return super(uint16, Offset16).__new__(Offset16, val)
```

and per the MRO for `Offset16` and the semantics for `super` mentioned above, that resolves to

```py
        return int.__new__(Offset16, val)
```

That explains why the changed definition results in a different behaviour.

---

Second: *What's the best way to do this?*

Different alternatives were provided in comments that might fit different situations.

[@juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) suggested (assuming Python3) simply using `super()` without arguments. For the approach that was being taken in the question, this makes sense. The reason for passing arguments to `super` would be to manipulate the MRO search. In this simple class hierarchy, that's not needed.

[@Jason Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11936135/jason-yang) suggested referring directly to the specific superclass rather than using `super`. For instance:

```py
class Offset16(uint16):

    def __new__(cls, val):
        return uint16.__new__(cls, val)
```

That is perfectly fine for this simple situation. But it might not be the best for other scenarios with more complex class relationships. Note, for instance, that `uint16` is duplicated in the above. If the subclass had several methods that wrapped (rather than replaced) the superclass method, there would be many duplicate references, and making changes to the class hierarchy would result in hard-to-analyze bugs. Avoiding such problems is one of the intended benefits for using `super`.

Finally, [@Adam.Er8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5052365/adam-er8) suggested simply using

```py
Offset16 = uint16
```

That's very simple, indeed. The one caveat is that `Offset16` is truly no more than an alias for `uint16`; it's not a separate class. For example:

```py
>>> Offset16 = uint16
>>> x = Offset16(24)
>>> type(x)
<class 'uint16'>
```

So, this may be fine *so long as there's never a need in the app to have an actual type distinction*.